# Convergence of Fourier transform in $L^p$

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider a sequence $f_n \to f$ convergent in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N) \cap L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Prove that the respective Fourier transforms
$$ \hat{f_n} \to \hat{f} $$
in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N) \ \forall p > 2$.
$$
$$
Resolution:

By hipothesis, $\Vert f_n - f \Vert_2 \to 0$, where $\Vert * \Vert_2$ denotes the norm in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Let $p > 2$. Denoting $ \Vert * \Vert_p $ by the norm in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$,

$$
0 \leq \Vert \hat{f_n} - \hat{f} \Vert_p^p = \int_{\mathbb{R^N}} \vert \hat{f_n} - \hat{f} \vert^p \\ = \int_{\mathbb{R^N}} \vert \hat{f_n} - \hat{f} \vert^2 \ \vert \hat{f_n} - \hat{f} \vert^{p-2}
$$
I know that
$$
\Vert \hat{f_n} - \hat{f} \Vert_2 = \Vert \widehat{f_n - f} \Vert_2 = \dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^N} \Vert f_n - f \Vert_2 \to 0
$$
when $ n \to + \infty$.

Do we have $ \Vert \hat{f_n} - \hat{f} \Vert_{p-2}^{p-2} < C$, for some constant $ C \geq 0 $ ? Why?

Comment: What does convergent in $L^{2}\cap L^{1}$ mean? Does it mean convergent in both $L^{1}$ and $L^{2}$ norms?

Comment: $L^2 \cap L^1$ is a Banach space in its own right with the norm $\| \cdot\| = \|\cdot\|_2 + \|\cdot\|_1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $ \mathbb{R}^N $ is ilimited, and so the definition of Fourier transform may not make any sense for functions in $L^2$ - the definition is given in $L^1$. Then, we use the notation $ L^2 \cap L^1 $ to say that the Fourier transform in $L^2$ is defined as an extension of that transformation defined in some densed subspace in $L^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Fourier transform of an $L^{1}$ function $f$ is bounded by $\|f\|_1$. $f_n \to f$ in $L^{1}(\mathbb R^{n})$ implies that $\|f_n\|_1$ is a bounded sequence. So $\int |\hat {f_n}-\hat f|^{p} \leq (\sup_x |\hat {f_n}(x)-\hat f(x)|)^{p-2} \|f_n-f\|_2^{2}  \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!